# How to make a HtmlTable class work with Mootools 1.3

Tags: javascript, html, mootools

I want to create an event when i click on a list of item it will will produce a table with the result of a link tag and some text on td, and i am using MooTools.

My problem here is that whenever i open up my `html` code with browser and inspect the code, after i click on a list of item, with developer tool on chrome and firebug on firefox it says:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: HtmlTable is not defined.

Here is mycode:

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools-core-1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools-more-1.3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pop-up.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/pop-up.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
        <h1>Pop Ups</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Good Bros</li>
            <li>Kinds</li>
            <li>Helpful</li>
            <li>Good Knowledge</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="over-lay"></div>
        <div id="pop-up">
            <div class="menu-tab">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" title="#">Act</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="#">NSW</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="#">QLD</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="#">SA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="#">TAS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="#">VIC</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="#">WA</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="pop-up-content">
            </div>
            <div id="pagination">
                append pagination link
            </div>
        </div>
</div>      
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
window.addEvent('load', function(){


//create new element
    //create table as a global variable
    var table;
    var link = 'http://www.google.com';
    var linkText = 'Atlanta';
    var address = 'cd and R Winne St';      
    var myTable = new HtmlTable({
            properties: {
            border: 1,
            cellspacing: 3
        },
            headers: ['fruits', 'colors'],
            rows: [
                ['apple', 'red'],
                ['lemon', 'yellow']
            ]
    });
    //this is a function to add rows to table;
    var addRowToTable = function () {

        //loop to create 10 table rows
        for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
            //create a new <a> tag
            var aTag = new Element ('a', {
                href: link,
                title: 'Name of City',
                html: linkText,
            });
            //add row to table
            MyTable.push([aTag, address]);
        }
    }

    var li = $$('li');
    li.addEvent('click', function(){
        addRowToTable();        
    });
    //inject table to div pop-up-content
    table.inject($('pop-up-content'));

});
```

Comment: should it not be `myTable.inject($('pop-up-content'));` instead of `table`?

Comment: Thank you @Sergio i have figured it out just now and here is my solution, i put it here on jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/meily/m4ms8La9/

Comment: Great. Just curious: should the new rows be the same link/text or connected to the clicked one?

Comment: In facts I want to do it this way, let's say I have a json file and i want to retrieve data from that json file, and now i am stuck in there, i will start a new question tonight.

Comment: Since this question is already answered you could re-do-it by [edit]ing it so we can look at it again.

Comment: Okay I will re-edit the article